# Indicating a npm package is server side only?

Tags: npm

Are there any ways to indicate in a package.json that package is only for server side usage?

I ran into an issue where some developers were trying to use a library of mine in the browser, but because of implementation could only work server side. Beyond clarifying that in the documentation, is it possible to specify in the package.json, so npm could flag it?

I did look in the npm install process and did not notice anything there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a discussion about this but no official answer. Please check https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/4321. Some people are using the "engines" field to indicate a node package maybe. Others use tags, and others try to add "browser": true field in the package.json.

But until now, there's no official way.

---

*[Edit: 2020]*

The [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#main) says they settled on "main" with the entrypoint (e.g. `"main": "server.js"`), plus `"browser": false`.